# How to create a DIB after loading a 32-bit PNG image with alpha channel?

Tags: c++, winapi, bitmap, gdi

I want to use the `BITMAPINFO` structure to define the DIB of the 32-bit png image, so that I can then use `StretchDIBits` to send the image to the printer for printing.
I tried the following code:

```cpp
HDC memDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hdcPrinter);
BITMAPINFO bmi = { 0 };
bmi.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
bmi.bmiHeader.biWidth = width;
bmi.bmiHeader.biHeight = -static_cast<int>(height);
bmi.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
bmi.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 32; 
bmi.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
void* bits = NULL;
HBITMAP dib = CreateDIBSection(memDC, &bmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS, &bits, NULL, 0);

//...
```

But I'm not sure if this will lose the alpha channel of the image.

Comment: For the printer, an "alpha channel" is completely useless because the paper will not become transparent when printing. For this reason, the printer does not accept an "alpha channel". Unfortunately, you will have to calculate the "real color" (RGB) from the RGBA-value and the color of the paper (probably white) yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Your `BITMAPINFO` structure is constructed correctly. As a sidenote, you can use [Windows Imaging Component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wic/-wic-lh) to convert.

References:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1360203/how-use-32bit-bitmap-for-menus-in-win32-app

https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/ac06e54a15e9a62443e400fffff190fb978ea586/Samples/Win7Samples/winui/shell/appshellintegration/RecipeThumbnailProvider/RecipeThumbnailProvider.cpp#L249

```
HRESULT ConvertBitmapSourceTo32BPPHBITMAP(IWICBitmapSource *pBitmapSource,
                                           IWICImagingFactory *pImagingFactory,
                                           HBITMAP *phbmp)
{
    *phbmp = NULL;

    IWICBitmapSource *pBitmapSourceConverted = NULL;
    WICPixelFormatGUID guidPixelFormatSource;
    HRESULT hr = pBitmapSource->GetPixelFormat(&guidPixelFormatSource);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr) && (guidPixelFormatSource != GUID_WICPixelFormat32bppBGRA))
    {
        IWICFormatConverter *pFormatConverter;
        hr = pImagingFactory->CreateFormatConverter(&pFormatConverter);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            // Create the appropriate pixel format converter
            hr = pFormatConverter->Initialize(pBitmapSource, GUID_WICPixelFormat32bppBGRA, WICBitmapDitherTypeNone, NULL, 0, WICBitmapPaletteTypeCustom);
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
            {
                hr = pFormatConverter->QueryInterface(&pBitmapSourceConverted);
            }
            pFormatConverter->Release();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        hr = pBitmapSource->QueryInterface(&pBitmapSourceConverted);  // No conversion necessary
    }

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        UINT nWidth, nHeight;
        hr = pBitmapSourceConverted->GetSize(&nWidth, &nHeight);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            BITMAPINFO bmi = {};
            bmi.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(bmi.bmiHeader);
            bmi.bmiHeader.biWidth = nWidth;
            bmi.bmiHeader.biHeight = -static_cast<LONG>(nHeight);
            bmi.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
            bmi.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 32;
            bmi.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;

            BYTE *pBits;
            HBITMAP hbmp = CreateDIBSection(NULL, &bmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS, reinterpret_cast<void **>(&pBits), NULL, 0);
            hr = hbmp ? S_OK : E_OUTOFMEMORY;
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
            {
                WICRect rect = {0, 0, nWidth, nHeight};

                // Convert the pixels and store them in the HBITMAP.  Note: the name of the function is a little
                // misleading - we're not doing any extraneous copying here.  CopyPixels is actually converting the
                // image into the given buffer.
                hr = pBitmapSourceConverted->CopyPixels(&rect, nWidth * 4, nWidth * nHeight * 4, pBits);
                if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                {
                    *phbmp = hbmp;
                }
                else
                {
                    DeleteObject(hbmp);
                }
            }
        }
        pBitmapSourceConverted->Release();
    }
    return hr;
}
```